# PL/PgSQL,retornar una funcion con muchos "%" como una columna (Dice que retorno más de una columna)

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

Le envio un Integer y quiero que me devuelva ese varchar con muchos % (Equivalente a cada billete) Pero dice que me devuelve más de una columna, como si asumiese que el texto no es una unidad, si no devolviedno cada % por separado

CODIGO:

````
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dinero(IN euros INTEGER) returns VARCHAR as $$
DECLARE

quinientos INTEGER:= 0;
doscientos INTEGER:= 0;
(...)
billetes VARCHAR;

BEGIN
WHILE euros >= 500
LOOP
quinientos := quinientos +1;
euros := euros-500;
END LOOP;
WHILE euros >= 200
LOOP
doscientos := doscientos +1;
euros := euros-200;
END LOOP;

(...)

billetes := '% billetes de 500 % billetes de 200 % billetes de 100 % billetes de 50 % billetes de 20 % billetes de 10 % billetes de 5', quinientos, doscientos, cien, cincuenta, veinte, diez, cinco;

RETURN billetes;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;```
````

Comment: Hello, we are in Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Answer (score 0):

esa operación con de asignacion no es posible de eso modo(eso funciona para los `RAISE` y otras), pero en este caso puedes utilizar las concatenación

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dinero(IN euros INTEGER) returns VARCHAR as $$
DECLARE

quinientos INTEGER:= 0;
doscientos INTEGER:= 0;
(...)
billetes VARCHAR;

BEGIN
WHILE euros >= 500
LOOP
quinientos := quinientos +1;
euros := euros-500;
END LOOP;
WHILE euros >= 200
LOOP
doscientos := doscientos +1;
euros := euros-200;
END LOOP;

(...)

billetes := quinientos ||' billetes de 500 '|| doscientos||' billetes de 200 '|| cien ||' billetes de 100 '|| cincuenta ||' billetes de 50'|| veinte ||' billetes de 20'|| diez ||' billetes de 10 '|| cinco||' billetes de 5'; 
RETURN billetes;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Se suele usar la función format:

````
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dinero(IN euros INTEGER) returns VARCHAR as $$
DECLARE

quinientos INTEGER:= 0;
doscientos INTEGER:= 0;
(...)
billetes VARCHAR;

BEGIN
WHILE euros >= 500
LOOP
quinientos := quinientos +1;
euros := euros-500;
END LOOP;
WHILE euros >= 200
LOOP
doscientos := doscientos +1;
euros := euros-200;
END LOOP;

(...)

billetes := format('%s billetes de 500 %s billetes de 200 %s billetes de 100 %s billetes de 50 %s billetes de 20 %s billetes de 10 %s billetes de 5', quinientos, doscientos, cien, cincuenta, veinte, diez, cinco);

RETURN billetes;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;```
````